# Grails Asset Pipeline not giving proper Javascript order

Tags: angularjs, grails, asset-pipeline

I'm creating an Angular app on Grails 3.1.5 and asset pipeline is not giving me the Javascript file ordering I need.  I have the following Javascript files:

`angello.js`

```js
//= require /angular/angular
//= require /angular-route/angular-route
//= require /angello/core/angello.core
//= require /angello/index/angello.index
//= require /angello/common/angello.common
//= require /angello/storyboard/angello.storyboard

var myModule = angular.module("Angello", [
    "angello.core",
    "angello.index",
    'ngRoute',
    'Angello.Common',
    'Angello.Storyboard'
]);

myModule.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'assets/angello/storyboard/tmpl/storyboard.html',
            controller: 'StoryboardCtrl',
            controllerAs: 'storyboard'
        })
});
myModule.controller('MainCtrl', function() { });
```

`angello.storyboard.js`

```js
//= require_tree services
//= require_tree controllers
//= require_tree directives
//= require_tree templates
//= require_self

angular.module('Angello.Storyboard', ['Angello.Common']);
```

`storyboardController.js`

```js
//= require /angular/angular
//= require /angello/storyboard/angello.storyboard
//= require_self

angular.module('Angello.Storyboard')
    .controller('StoryboardCtrl', function() {
        var storyboard = this;
    });
```

I include all of this in my main GSP with 
`<asset:javascript src="angello.js" />`  When the HTML is rendered, the order of the JS files are not what I expect:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/angular/angular.js?compile=false" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/angular-route/angular-route.js?compile=false" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/angular/angular-resource.js?compile=false" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/angello/core/angello.core.js?compile=false" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/angello/core/services/DomainServiceFactory.js?compile=false" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/angello/index/angello.index.js?compile=false" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/angello/index/services/applicationDataFactory.js?compile=false" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/angello/index/controllers/indexController.js?compile=false" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/angular/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js?compile=false" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/angello/common/angello.common.js?compile=false" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/angello/storyboard/controllers/storyboardController.js?compile=false" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/angello/storyboard/angello.storyboard.js?compile=false" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/angello.js?compile=false" ></script>
```

The problem is that storyboard JS files are included in the order opposite of what I need, resulting in angular complaining

`Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'Angello.Storyboard' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.`

I think this is a problem in the way I have structured the dependency directives.  I have tried many different things, but nothing seems to affect the order.

Comment: In `angello.storyboard.js` `controllers` are required before the module itself. So, when the controller (`styoryBoardController.js`) is required it complains about the module not being present. Try moving `//= require_self` to the top in `angello.storyboard.js`. There can be optimized fixed as well.

Comment: @dmahapatro that did the trick!  Please post as an answer and I'll be happy to mark it correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `module` which is used to create the artifacts like `controller`, `service`, etc has to be loaded first before the dependents are loaded. In the above case controllers are required before the module itself.

So, when the controller (`styoryBoardController.js`) is required it complains about the module not being present.

Moving `//= require_self` to the top in `angello.storyboard.js` will ensure that the module itself is required first then the dependencies.